# DOCROOT in local vs development

Tags: php

I am working to revise a php application. It happens to use the FileMaker api for php, but that is largely irrelevant for this question. The app uses DOCROOT is a number of places for file includes. This seems to work fine in production, however in my local development environment, it seems like the include files are failing to load. For example:

```
include(DOCROOT . "/lib/db/fm_connect.php"); // filemaker connectivity
```

I printed DOCROOT in production and get the following:

```
/home/customerName/public_html
```

In my local development environment DOCROOT is:

```
/Library/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/htdocs
```

Since DOCROOT is called in many places in this app, how can I revise this so that it works both in production and local development?

Note that the FileMaker server runs its own webserver in the path described above.

Comment: It looks like the problem is induced by spaces in `DOCROOT`. Try to `DOCROOT = preg_replace('/\s/', '\ ', DOCROOT)` in the very beginning of your code.

Comment: Well actually it turns out that DOCROOT was not defined.  It was used later in the code, but defined before those usage instances.  I defined DOCROOT in another place and it is working.